# Grails : Error Command not found dbm-generate-gorm-changelog

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 3.1.6 and while using database migration with(Game.groovy is my model):

```
grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog-add createGame.groovy
```

It shows:

```
| Error Command not found dbm-generate-gorm-changelog-add
Did you mean: generate-all or generate-views or generate-controller?
```

N.B: **I have Available Plugins Named "database-migration"**

Need help here.

Comment: grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog createGame.groovy  and also in your  IDE (eclipse or Intellij) try to refresh dependencies

Comment: with command : grails refresh-dependencies

Comment: It is saying "| Error Command not found refresh-dependencies
Did you mean: dependency-report or open or test?"

Comment: oh sorry certainly this not the same command for grails 3.x (I'm using grails 2.4.5, there is no gradle but maven)

Answer (score 3):

I manually added

`compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'` and

`compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.2'`   in 
`build.gradle`  file

Added  `classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC4'` in main section  also .

That is the solution of the problem.